# Increase max-request-parameters in Glass Fish Server

Tags: glassfish

WARNING: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([10,000]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.

I can find solution for tomcat but i cannot find any better solution for Glass Fish Server.....

Comment: Do you want to ask a question?

Comment: i need to know how to configure the max parameter count in GLass fish server

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish has a property called max-request-parameters after version 3.1.2.5. If your glassfish version is newer than 3.1.2.5 you can use the asadmin command line util to run a command like this

```
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-request-parameters=10001
```

you can find more at this link https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2013-08/message/23